# Estimate growing graphs

Tags: graphing-functions, estimation

Lets make my scenario not generic just so that i could use particular terms

Say i have a graph of population per year of someplace over some decades

[Lets say the graph is like this](https://www.google.com.pk/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&met_y=sp_pop_totl&tdim=true&dl=en&hl=en&q=total%20population%20of%20world#!ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=sp_pop_totl&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=region&ifdim=region&tdim=true&hl=en_US&dl=en&ind=false)

- How can i calculate expected\estimated population next year and son on and so forth

Comment: Do you mean like doing a linear regression of the data points to determine a slope covering all the data points or something else?  Could you quantify how you'd measure "speed of growth of the graph as a whole"?

Answer (score 1):

The link doesn't work for me, but your first stop should be [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).  If you take the logarithm of the population you will be looking for an exponential increase-a fixed percentage change per year instead of a fixed number change per year.  This is probably a better fit.  Any numerical analysis text will have a chapter on this, or you can get Excel to do it.  Graph the data as a scatter plot, right click on the graph, choose Add Trendline, and pick the kind of trendline you want.